# Text overflow ellipsis the dots should be center of the text

Tags: html, css

I want the ellipsis dots should be center of the text. When I use the `text-overflow: ellipsis`, it shows the dots last, while I want them to be centered.

```css
p.test1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18</p>
```

The above example shows the result like this

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9...`

Expected result something like is:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 13 14 15 16 17 18`

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to achieve should depend on `CSS` but on a serverside language like `PHP` for example, or client side `JavaScript/jQuery`. It looks like you're trying to fake a pagination or you don't understand how a pagination should work.

Comment: Nopes. The `text-overflow: ellipsis` works only on *overflow*, it can not arbitrarily break the text. You will need to script that logic.

Comment: you would need js for this (or as lonut says, a server side language)

Comment: is it not possible to achieve by using css?

Comment: Nope, it's not possible.

Comment: @lonut  I am not trying fake pagination, i am going to truncate the text but i need to display last word of the sentence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not done by using pure CSS, So i found the solution with the help of jQuery.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="example">
        <h1>How to display Text-Overflow:ellipsis dots in center of the text</h1>
        <p><strong>Truncate text using jQuery</strong></p>
        <div class="r">
            <div class="box after pathname" id="dot5">
                <div class="pathname">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae pretium mauris. Ut tincidunt arcu diam, in congue elit efficitur id. Nunc maximus diam et tellus tincidunt, vitae placerat lacus ullamcorper.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.r {
    width: 275px;
    background-color:red;
}

div.box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.pathname {
    height: 25px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dot5 .pathname').each(function() {
        var path = $(this).html().split(' ');
        if (path.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var name = path.pop();
        $(this).html(path.join( ' ' ) + '<span class="filename">' + name + '</span>');
        $(this).dotdotdot({
            after: '.filename',
            wrap: 'letter'
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo Here](http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/03/how-to-display-text-overflowellipsis.html)

Comment: working fine in demo page ,but we need to insert jquery file dotdotdot.js file!

Comment: yes we should include jquery.dotdotdot.js and jquery files!

Answer (score 7):

One simple solution would be to add a span inside the p tag and make it show ellipsis on text overflow, and add the last word after the span tag.

```css
p.test1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.elips {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1"><span class="elips">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12</span> 13 14 15 16 17 18 Add Last word here</p>
```

Comment: It's a novel idea.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible with pure css but if you are unable to use js or a server side language to achieve what you want, you can  use the following - it's a bit of a hack but works quite well.  The only downside is that you will be duplicating your numbers:

```css
p.test1 {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

p > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.ellipsis {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% + 1.2em);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.indent {
  display:inline-flex;
  width: calc(50% - 1.2em);
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">
  <span class="ellipsis">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18</span><!--
  --><span class="indent">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18</span>
</p>
```

[Here is a fiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/4bmwz8do/1) - change the p width and you will see how it works, not perfect but the best you'll get with pure css without manually calculating where the split will be

Comment: This seems to work but has the issue that when selecting everything to copy/paste you'll have the information twice.

Comment: @Crystark Quoted from my answer:  *"The only downside is that you will be duplicating your numbers:"*

Comment: Yes, I was just stating for those that wouldn't understand the implications right away one of the effects it has.

Comment: This is working well if the string is long but if the string is short, for example "1 2 3 4 5 6", two same strings are displayed like "1 2 3 4 5 6       1 2 3 4 5 6".

Comment: this is perfect solution for css only. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Because it's way past jQuery here is a more simple pure-js implementation:

- set ellipsis position either by percentage or number of chars counted from the end
- sets title attribute with original text
- calculates by canvas metrics
- recalculates on debounced resize (only when element size has changed)
- recalculation uses cached variables

(tested on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Chrome Android)

```js
/**
 * Attibute modifier to create middle ellipsis
 * When the attribute value is left blank the ellipsis will be in the middle
 * When positive the attribute value will be used as a percentage
 * When negative the attribute value will be used as character index counted from the end
 * @example
 *   <div data-middle-ellipsis>A Javascript solution to middle ellipsis</div>
 *   <div data-middle-ellipsis="20">A Javascript solution to middle ellipsis</div>
 *   <div data-middle-ellipsis="-3">A Javascript solution to middle ellipsis</div>
 */
const attributeName = 'data-middle-ellipsis'
const clamp = (val,min=Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,max=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)=>Math.max(min,Math.min(max,val))
const ellipsis = '…'
const map = new Map()
let timeoutId

testMiddleEllipsis()
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, { capture: true, passive: true })
function onResize(e){
  clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  timeoutId = setTimeout(testMiddleEllipsis, 200)
}

function testMiddleEllipsis() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[${attributeName}]`)).forEach(elm=>{
    // do not recalculate variables a second time
    const mapped = map.get(elm)
    let {text, textLength, from, multiplier, font, textWidth, elementWidth} = mapped||{}
    // first time
    if (!mapped) {
     text = elm.textContent
      textLength = text.length
      from = parseFloat(elm.getAttribute(attributeName))||50
      multiplier = from>0&&from/100
      const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elm, null)
      font = `${computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-weight')} ${computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-size')} ${computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-family')}`
      textWidth = getTextWidth(text, font)
      elementWidth = elm.offsetWidth
      map.set(elm, {text, textLength, from, multiplier, font, textWidth, elementWidth})
    }
    //
    const {offsetWidth} = elm
    const widthChanged = !mapped||elementWidth!==offsetWidth
    mapped&&widthChanged&&(mapped.elementWidth=elementWidth=offsetWidth)
    //
    if (widthChanged&&textWidth>elementWidth) {
      elm.setAttribute('title', text)
      let smallerText = text
      let smallerWidth = elementWidth
      while(smallerText.length>3){
        let smallerTextLength = smallerText.length
        const half = multiplier&&
            clamp(multiplier*smallerTextLength<<0,1,smallerTextLength-2)||
            Math.max(smallerTextLength+from-1,1)
        const half1 = smallerText.substr(0,half).replace(/\s*$/,'')
        const half2 = smallerText.substr(half+1).replace(/^\s*/,'')
        smallerText = half1+half2
        smallerWidth = getTextWidth(smallerText+ellipsis, font)
        if (smallerWidth<elementWidth) {
          elm.textContent = half1+ellipsis+half2
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

/**
 * Get the text width
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {string} font
 */
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
  let context = getTextWidth.context
  if (!context) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    context = getTextWidth.context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  }
  context.font = font
  const metrics = context.measureText(text)
  return metrics.width
}
```

```css
html,body{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  line-height: 170%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #fff linear-gradient(90deg
    ,transparent 130px
    ,#f0f0f0 130px
    ,#f0f0f0 260px
    ,transparent 260px
  );
}

[data-middle-ellipsis]{
  max-width: 130px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 red inset;
}

.inline-block { display: inline-block; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.small { font-size: 10px; }
.large { font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<main>
<h1 data-middle-ellipsis>A Javascript solution to middle ellipsis</h1>
<div data-middle-ellipsis>The quick fox</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis class="inline-block">The lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis>theQuickBrownFoxJumpsOverTheLazyDog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis class="bold">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis class="small">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis class="small bold">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis class="large">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="70">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="30">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="1">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="99">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="-3">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="-3">The quick brown dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="0">The quick brown dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="-1">The quick brown dog</div>
<div data-middle-ellipsis="-99">The quick brown dog</div>
</main>
```

Comment: This works great when the window resizes, but doesn't apply the resizing when pertaining elements render on the page the first time. 

How would you suggest applying this resize logic for the first render?

Comment: Works here on mobile Chrome. You could try calling the first function call with a `requestAnimationFrame`.